# Figure out the total disk space utilization per process

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, disk-usage, proc

I am looking for best way to determine how much each of my process has consumed in terms of disk space. As I see, there is only one option in front of me. That is to fetch the `write_bytes` from `/proc/<pid>/io` output from all the process and sum them up. But then I see a mis-match in terms of the total which I get by doing this to what `df -h` gives me.

Comment: None of those numbers in diskstat are disk usage. It contains information on I/O stats.

Comment: The 8th column represents the total number of writes. But i do not know what each write size is.

Comment: I also looked at the /proc/<pid>/io stats and collected the write_bytes from all the PID's. That sum actually came upto 4GB which was not matching the 99GB disk space being used. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: @Jesse_b: My end goal is to figure out which process is leading to maximum disk utilization on a timely manner to define some data purge policies so that i do not run out of disk space at any given point in time.

Comment: Do you want to know the rate that each process is writing, or the cumulative amount that each process has written? Is a process writing 1MB/sec for a week better or worse than a process started a minute ago that is writing 100MB/sec?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick All i want is to know how much the process has written to disk. Not the rate at which the writes happen.

Comment: You talked about 4GB vs 99GB. Are you sure that all 99GB was written solely by processes that are currently running?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Well the block device of my interest was completely used by the node which had the kubernetes standalone cluster

Comment: The docker processes (or whatever you used) that downloaded the images and created the containers may have exited a long time ago. The processes in the containers that wrote even more stuff may have exited a long time ago. Sadly, /proc/pid/io doesn't include all of the i/o of a process' descendants, so if you're monitoring current processes all you have is a snapshot of filesystem activity. Would being able to quickly check the rate of change of disk usage for every container be useful? The disk quota system may help (even if you wish to have infinite quotas).

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this pipe:

```
iotop -qqq -b -Paok -n 2 -d 30 | sort -n -k6 -r | head -n 20
```

Options:

`-qqq` : don't print headers and summary
`-b` : batch-mode
`-P` : show only processes, not all therads
`-a` : accumulated I/O
`-k` : print results in kilobytes
`-n 2` : number of runs, from what I can understand, it must be >= 2 since the first one last less than 1 sec
`-d 30` : delay between runs, aka total run in this case, approximately
`| sort -n -k6 -r` : numerically sort by 6th column (total writes) and reverse the order
`| head -n 20` : show only the first 20 lines

**Note** : It shows only how much processes have written, not the total physical space used. If a process continuously write the same file of 20KB, once per sec, you end up having 20KB of space usage but in 30 sec a total write of 600KB. In this case I would monitor the directories my processes write into, with `du`

Comment: One thing which i wanted to know is if iotop actually starts incrementing counters from the time its run or will it also capture the already written data info on a per process basis no matter when i start iotop ?

Comment: @Raks, It starts collecting data from the time you run it but you can easily put a line in crontab (eg. `@reboot /usr/sbin/iotop <arguments>`) - or make a init service :) - to have a continuous log.

Comment: Is there a way to collect the number of bytes each process has deleted on disk over a period of time ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/). This will show you disk usage in real time per process. Assuming you are using CentOS/Fedora, you can do.

```
$ sudo yum install iotop
```

Then just invoke with `iotop`.

Comment: iotop gives me the read/write throughput while i am interested in space consumption on disk.

Comment: Why can't you use `iotop -a` ?

Comment: How do i customize this to display just the top 20 consumers of disk space ?